# string replace for new line is not working for json string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, replace

I searched a lot to figure out solution to my problem but nothing seemed to work. I am trying to load some text from database into page. Before loading I am parsing it as JSON string.

The Text I need to load from database is

> Qty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT \n 
>   Qty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT Accessory: Power Filter

Initially when I tried to parse it was throwing an exception as unexpected expression and I figured it the reason as new line character. So I inserted below piece of code

```
str = Replace(str, vbCrLf, "\n")
```

Now I am able to parse and the output is

> Qty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT Qty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT

The problem is I want the text to be displayed in the same format as it is in the database. I tried to change `'\n'` in above code with `"\\n"`, `""`, `"<br />"` ... and other options suggested in the internet but nothing seemed to work out and I am getting the same output as one long text instead of two separate texts. Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what language are you using?

Comment: When you use "<br />", can you use F12 (in IE) to see what the HTML is coming out as?  And post it here please.

Comment: @JimW I am little confused with your question. Can you be more clear

Comment: @OP, what I mean is, load your page, then press F12 (in IE), and browse through the source to find where your problem is, then copy the HTML from there and post it please.

Comment: @JimW Thank you. To be clear I used str = replace(str, vbCrlf, "<br />") in .vb file. So in my .aspx file all the javascript and ajax calls are there. When I loaded my page in IE and did F12 its just showing the ajaxcall code and usercontrol code. If you still think it will be useful I will post it.  Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, so you're doing this on the server side Response.Write(str) - what is processing that on the client side?  Although I do have ASP.NET AJAX experience I don't deal with it that freq. so apologies if silly question.

Comment: @JimW: The desired output is ("str") is loaded into a grid. I am using kendogrid

Answer (score 0):

`\n` has to be replaced with `\\n`. The backslash needs to be escaped before it can be used in the JSON string.

Comment: I already tried with "\\n" then in the output \n is shown like below
"Qty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT\nQty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT Accessory: Power Filter"  Thankyou

Comment: How, precisely, are you adding it to the page?

Comment: you mean it is stripping out the spaces before and after the \n?

Comment: @jcolebrand Once text is retrived (after parsing) I am printing it. My printfucntion is :  
Private Sub printJSON(ByVal str As String)
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Response.Write(str)
        Response.End()
    End Sub

Comment: Does it help ?
str = Replace(str, "\n", " \\n ")

Comment: If I give str = replace(str, "\n", "\\n") its throwing an exception as unexpected expression. then only I figured it out that I need to pass either vbCrLf or environment.newline as second parameter to replace function. Then exception is gone, able to parse but output is one long text instead of two (which is supposed to be correct)

Comment: Could you then post your solution please?

Comment: @Tariqulazam: My output when I use str=replace(str,vbCrLf,"\\n") then output is:     "Qty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT\nQty: 1 Model#: MX-M350UCT Accessory: Power Filter"      and I hope you see the \n between two texts (each textline starts with Qty) and it is showing as one long text line instead of two

Comment: Please update your question with new code samples and results so they are formatted properly

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention kendo grid, here's what you need.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/line-breaks-in-grid-cell.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much will look into the link